# Evaluating JSP EL without a Servlet container

Tags: unit-testing, jsp, el

Here's what I want to do:

```
Map<String, Object> model = new Hashmap<String, Object>();
model.put("a", "abc");
model.put("b", new Hashmap<String, Object>());
model.get("b").put("c", "xyz");
String el = "A is ${a} and C is ${b.c}";
assertEquals(elEval(el, model), "A is abc and C is xyz");
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , it is possible , you can refer to this [link](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2008/04/java-using-el-outside-j2ee.html) for more information . As you can see , in order to use the EL expression standalone , you would have to  implement several classes such as the `javax.el.ELContext` . I found [JUEL](http://juel.sourceforge.net/) , which is one of the implementation of the EL expression , already provides  very nice implementations of these classes in the `de.odysseus.el.util` package.

I have played around with JUEL .Here is my testing code for your reference:

```
/*
ExpressionFactoryImpl should be the implementation of ExpressionFactory used by  your application server. 
For example , in tomcat 7.0 , it is org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl , which is inside the jasper-el.jar .
jasper-el.jar  is the implemenation of EL expression provided by tomcat  , el-api.jar is the API of EL expression (i.e. JSR-245)
*/
ExpressionFactory factory = new ExpressionFactoryImpl();

/*
SimpleContext is the utility classes from fuel 
*/
SimpleContext context = new SimpleContext();    

//Set the variables in the context  
Map<String,Object> hashMap =  new HashMap<String,Object>();
hashMap.put("c", "xyz");
context.setVariable("a", factory.createValueExpression("abc", String.class));   
context.setVariable("b", factory.createValueExpression(hashMap, HashMap.class));    

//Create the EL expression 
ValueExpression expr = factory.createValueExpression(context,  "A is ${a} and C is ${b.c}", String.class);  
System.out.println(expr.getValue(context));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. EL is an integral part of JSP and the JSP compiler will actually output a lot of stuff in the Servlet et generates from the JSP file. At the end of the day, the methods on [ExpressionFactory](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ExpressionFactory.html) are called, and you could do the same thing to evaluate your EL expression (after setting up an appropriate `ELContext`).

You would probably be better off using `String.format`, but it is possible...

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing this to unit test JSP expressions so String.format doesn't help :)

Comment: In that case, it is better for you to run the whole file through the JSP compiler, load the class and test it. The compiler in Tomcat is called Jasper. You can download it and run it separately on your files.